# Read document in existing window if already open

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

Trying to read word document and show user specific heading in the document.

If the document isn't open, it currently opens it. Currently, regardless, it will open the document in a new window.

I trying to get it to read it in the currently open window if the document is already open in it.

Tried looking for answers on other forums/stack overflow along with Microsoft documentation but I'm lost finding a solution.

```
public void DocumentPreview(string headingNumber, string headingName,string inputPath)
{
    var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var document = application.Documents.Open(FileName: inputPath);

    foreach (Paragraph paragraph in document.Paragraphs)
    {
        Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Style;
        string styleName = style.NameLocal;
        string text = paragraph.Range.Text;
        if ((styleName == "Heading 1") || (styleName == "Heading 2") ||
            (styleName == "Heading 3") || (styleName == "Heading 4"))
        {
            List<string> headingSplit = headingName.Split().ToList();
            double count = 0;
            foreach (string word in headingSplit)
            {
                if (text.ToString().ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()))
                {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            double accuracy = (count / headingSplit.Count());
            if (accuracy >= 0.5)
            {
                if (text.ToString().ToLower().Contains(headingNumber.ToLower()))
                {
                    Word.Range rng = paragraph.Range;
                    rng.Select();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently opens a document in a new window every time rather than in current window if-if already open.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use a single instance of word application by keeping it in a form field rather than a local variable. Then check if the `Documents` collection of the `Application` contains a `Document` having the same `Path` property value as `inputPath`, use it.

To do so, you can create such function:

```
//using MSWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
private MSWord.Document OpenDocument(MSWord.Application application, string inputPath)
{
    var documents = application.Documents;
    foreach (MSWord.Document item in documents)
        if (item.Path.ToUpper() == inputPath.ToUpper())
            return item;
    return documents.Open(FileName: inputPath);
}
```

As an example of the usage:

```
MSWord.Application application;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (application == null)
    {
        application = new MSWord.Application();
        application.Visible = true;
    }
    var document = OpenDocument(application, @"d:\test.docx");
    // ...
}
```

Make sure you `Quit` the application when you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful!